# launch/wake iOS app periodically

Tags: objective-c, ios7, nstimer

I have an app which runs in the Background. I'd like to wake it up periodically: either at preset times of day or every n hours. This must be done without user intervention.

I believe that since the app runs in Background, NSTimer will not work. How can I 'wake' my app on a periodic basis?

Answer (score 6):

Of course, that's possible, and is very easy to implement.
The technique is called Background Fetch.
It works like this -
1) You ask operation system to wake up / start your application on certain times.
2) Operation system decides and periodically start your application and calls

```
-(void)application:(UIApplication *)application performFetchWithCompletionHandler:(void (^)(UIBackgroundFetchResult))completionHandler
```

3) You do your jobs there, and also you can trigger local push notification to user, that new data is available.

here is a great [article that covers your question](http://www.doubleencore.com/2013/09/ios-7-background-fetch/)

Comment: Make sure you return something appropriate for the completion handler.  To get background CPU concisely it should be `completionHandler(UIBackgroundFetchNewData);`.  If you don't return anything, iOS will eventually stop waking your app up periodically.

Answer (score 0):

You can incorporate push notifications; however, the user would have to opt to open the notification.